# Pandas Dataframe reshaping with stack and unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to messing  with pandas stack and unstack. I was wondering if it is possible to reshape my data in this way.

This is my sample data which I am practicing.

```
ID,Value1,Value2
1,3,12
1,4,13
1,5,14
1,6,15
1,7,16
2,8,17
2,9,18
2,10,19
2,11,20
```

And I want to reshape in this way.

```
ID 
1   Index(Extra Column) Value1, value2
    1                      3    12
    2                      4    13
    3                      5    14
    4                      6    15
    5                      7    16

2
    1                      8    17
    2                      9    18
    3                      10   19
    4                      11   20
```

I tried this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[['Value1', 'Value2']], index= df['ID']).stack()
```

or

```
df1 = df.set_index(['ID']).stack()
```

this changes Value1 and Value2 from column to rows which I dont want.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose `set_index` + `cumcount` here:

```
df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1])

      Value1  Value2
ID                  
1  1       3      12
   2       4      13
   3       5      14
   4       6      15
   5       7      16
2  1       8      17
   2       9      18
   3      10      19
   4      11      20
```

---

Another option is using `concat`:

```
pd.concat({k : g.reset_index(drop=True) for k, g in df.drop('ID', 1).groupby(df.ID)})

     Value1  Value2
1 0       3      12
  1       4      13
  2       5      14
  3       6      15
  4       7      16
2 0       8      17
  1       9      18
  2      10      19
  3      11      20
```

Comment: one more question, do you know, what kind of format would be best to save this kind of output. Csv, excel, txt, dont save in proper way ?

Comment: @user3280146 It's a problem, none of these flat files support multiIndex. My advise would be to do `df = df.reset_index()` and then save to CSV. After that, when loading, specify `df = pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[0, 1])` which will read those two columns as multiindex.

Answer (score 3):

One way from apply

```
df.groupby('ID')[['Value1','Value2']].apply(lambda x : x.reset_index(drop=True))
Out[662]: 
      Value1  Value2
ID                  
1  0       3      12
   1       4      13
   2       5      14
   3       6      15
   4       7      16
2  0       8      17
   1       9      18
   2      10      19
   3      11      20
```

Answer (score 2):

### `defaultdict` and `count`

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(count)

df.set_index(['ID', np.array([next(d[x]) for x in df.ID])])

      Value1  Value2
ID                  
1  0       3      12
   1       4      13
   2       5      14
   3       6      15
   4       7      16
2  0       8      17
   1       9      18
   2      10      19
   3      11      20
```